# In iText 7 why checkbox is being checked if wrong value is set and CheckType changes from CHECK to CROSS

Tags: java, pdf, checkbox, itext, itext7

I am using iText 7 java library. Here are my gradle dependencies.

```
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'kernel', version: '7.1.9'
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'layout', version: '7.1.9'
compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'forms', version: '7.1.9'
```

I need to fill Acro form in an existing pdf template. PDF form has a checkbox defined with following settings -

**Name** = COMM_PREF_EMAIL

**Check Box Style** = Check

**Export Value** = Yes

[image]

If I open the pdf in acrobat reader and click the checbox, it shows checked with a check mark as expected.

[image]

With iText library, my expectation is that if I set checkbox value to Yes (matching to export value of the checkbox) then only checkbox should be checked. If I set any other value, checkbox should remain unchecked.

Here is my java code using iText 7 library.

```
PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
PdfFormField pdfFormField = pdfAcroForm.getField("COMM_PREF_EMAIL");
pdfFormField.setValue("B");
```

I am setting checkbox value as "B" which does not match export value "Yes" but still checkbox is being checked in the PDF and worst part is **Check Box Style** also changed to Cross. Below is how the checkbox looks after running this code.

[image]

Note that **Check Box Style** always changes to **Cross** irrespective of whatever value I set.

I did some debugging and noticed that when PdfFormField is retrieved using `getField`, it has `chekType=0`, which is not correct. Its not what is defined in the pdf. It should be 1 which is Check. Now when I call `pdfFormField.setValue(...)`, it eventually calls `regenerateField()` which I guess taking default value of chekType=3 (the cross) because it has invalid value.

[image]

Can someone help with following 2 issues -

1. Why checkbox is being checked if value being set does not match to export
   value?
2. Why setValue changing **Check Box Style** to **Cross**?

Any suggestion or advice is much appreciated.

**Update on 6/10/2020**
Link of pdf file to reproduce the issue https://github.com/rakeshprajapati1982/itext-7-issue/blob/master/Checklist.pdf

Comment: Hi, `7.1.11` is already out, please try with the latest version and if it does not work please provide your PDF so that the problem can be reproduced

Comment: I tested with iText `7.1.11` version as well and I see the same issue. I updated question with link of pdf in the end. You can use this pdf reproduce the issue. Checkex are towards end of the page in the pdf with label "Comm Preference"  Also note that original pdf size is 193KB but the filled pdf generated by iText is 152KB which is less than the original. I have seen more significant size drop in some other PDF files. Do you know reason of the size drop?

Answer (score 1):

As itextSharp with the method SetField() seems automatically gets the aparence of the form

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader_, fileStream);
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField(FIELD_NAME, "123",true);
```

but now in itext7 in my research seems like it's not implicit the widget shape "dove, cross, start, etc...", just it gets the values lets call'em states ("Yes, Off"), so just set the widget to type with SetCheckType(NUMBER) as mention in [Why does iText enter a cross symbol when CheckType](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/why-does-itext-enter-a-cross-symbol-when-checktype-style-is-check-mark)

so in your code it'll be like

```
            var field = form1.GetField(FIELD_NAME);
            if (field.GetType() == typeof(PdfButtonFormField)) {
                field.SetCheckType(PdfFormField.TYPE_CHECK);//PdfFormField.TYPE_CIRCLE,PdfFormField.TYPE_CROSS,PdfFormField.TYPE_DIAMOND,PdfFormField.TYPE_SQUARE,PdfFormField.TYPE_STAR,etc
                field.SetValue("Yes", true);
            }
```

By the way if I'm aswering in a bad way this question please be free to edit it don't delete it.